# Significance of Peter Parker's ringtone

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Peter's phone rings throughout the movie in a couple scenes (ex: Weapon selling scene).

The ringtone is very "loud" (it's not just a background noise, it is meant to be heard and focused on by the audience) and very distinctive.

Is the ringtone a reference to anything ? Or they did just give him that ringtone to emphasize on the goofy teenager aspect?

Comment: Its just to be funny.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has mostly been chosen to "emphasize on the goofy teenager aspect", as you put it. Peter is meant to be a relatable young kid (even though he's 15 - the aim was to give a hero to the younger audience of Marvel movies). At the beginning of the movie, when Ned shows up with the Emperor's Lego figurine and talks about his Lego Deathstar, Peter is obviously excited whereas the girls behind them say something like "so lame": he does not care about being the coolest guy at school (he is too busy being cool as Spiderman) and enjoys silly things just because they're enjoyeable. The ringtone is another example.
Also it is a classic way to break the tension built in a scene for a comic effect. BBC Sherlock used it at the beginning of its second season for instance.